# numeric value filter not working in kendo grid if value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Steps to Reproduce:

1. open dojo link pasted below
2. try applying filter on age value and select **Is  greater than equal to** and enter **0** and click on apply filter.

Observed: filtered result shows **null** values in list

Expected: null values should not be shown

Demo Link : [please check Dojo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/eHekUmuN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior and by design.

If you do not want null values to be present in the result, you also need to add a condition to the filter to excludes null.

[image]